# Invalid Doctrine Entity being created

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a web project that contains a mixture of Doctrine and traditional inline SQL for database access.  We're migrating from the latter to the former over time.

One of the database tables (Table A) has an informal foreign key (i.e. there are no actual constraints in the SQL table definition) column.  The value in this column is nullable, but sometimes the value in this column refers to a another table's (Table B) primary key that has since been deleted.

Table A's relationship with Table B is formalised in Table A's entity definition in Doctrine.  When I create an instance of an entity from an existing row in Table A and the informal foreign key column has a value that is no longer in Table B, then it seems an invalid Table B entity is created.  I.e. the object is set, and I can query it's id through the TableB->getId() method we have authored, but any other TableB->getProperty() fails and throws an error.

Since I'm already working with historic data, I need a run-time solution to this.  I need to identify via a check if the Table B entity is valid.
I could put it in a try-catch loop, but this is not a common pattern in our code base and does not seem very elegant.
Is there a canonical method for checking the validatity of a Doctrine entity to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: My opinion is that you are looking for a solution on framework level whereas the actual problem is on db/model level. I'd rather focus on creating clear data model that represents business requirements/reality better than existing one and implementing compatibility using database tools (views that return only "valid" data, triggers which synchronize data , etc). Then it's done and it works reliable, discard the old model, and use the new. Otherwise, you may end up with the system that if full of patches and hacks, and each next change will cause more and more efforts.

Comment: Agreed, and will be a longer term solution, but deadlines...

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, there are 2 things you should do.

First fix your data corruption, this is a must. If A points to a non-existing B, then A should not be pointing at all. `SELECT a.id FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.table_b_id WHERE b.id IS NULL`. This query will select all FK that are not existing anymore, you can simply update the `a.table_b_id` to NULL with that list.

Second, you should (not in your getter) take care of the relation issue in your code. I'm not sure if Doctrine throws an `EntityNotFoundException` or only does this with `find($pk)`, but I'm sure you can check if the return of your getter is `null` or catch that exception.

Comment: We can fix historic data, but the UI still allows users to get into this state.  We will address that, but not in this sprint.  Doctrine here is behaving very oddly - even a repository->find(pk) command is returning this invalid object.  Anyway, I did opt to wrap in a try-catch using the EntityNotFoundException.  Thanks for your help anyway - really appreciate it.

Comment: I am in constant similar situations regarding data-corruption etc. Fixing the data corruption however, will make it impossible for this to happen because it won't retrieve the objects in the first place as the relation "does not exist" from A to B ;) I have no clue how many tables this is about, but a fix like this on a few tables shouldn't take more than 30 minutes. From a developers POV, fixing this corruption will "autofix" the Doctrine issue and therefore cost you less hours ^.^

Comment: Yes, but the existing UI that gets you in this state isn't Doctrine yet, so until that is fixed the data can be corrupted by normal use.  The historic data fix is easy; translating old Backbone and a 1000 line PHP page with inline SQL is not so.